# How can I set specific elements to be disabled?

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
var row = 22;
```

How can I set it so that all my input and select elements that have 
IDs where XXX can be any combination of characters are disabled:

```
modal_XXX_22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `Multiple Attribute` selector:

```
$('*[id^="modal_"][id$="_'+row+'"]').prop('disabled', true)
// ^-  ^--           ^--- attribute ends with selector
//  |    |     
//  |    --- attribute starts with selector 
//  ---- all selector
```

1. [All Selector](http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/)
2. [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)
3. [Attribute Ends With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

Comment: Can you explain the difference between your use of $ and the other use of "*". I just tried your solution but it did not work. Might be another problem with my code and I am checking this out now.

Comment: @SamanthaJ The fist attribute selector selects the elements that their IDs begin with `modal_` substring, this is `attribute starts with` selector and the other one selects the elements that their IDs end with your variable's value.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot get this to work. The only thing working is if I specify the ids like this: $('#modal_Link_0').attr('disabled', 'disabled')

Comment: @SamanthaJ Can you post your codes? Do you see any error on the console?

Answer (score 2):

That is how you would select them:

```
$('[id^="modal_"][id$="_' + row + '"]').
```

Comment: @zwekms - This does not seem to work. I used the following code:          $('[id^="modal_"][id$="_' + oLink.row + '"]')
                .attr('disabled', 'disabled')
            $('#modal_Link_0').attr('disabled', 'disabled')  Only the element with the name modal_Link_0 was disabled. Others with similar names were not.

Comment: @Samantha J: what actual similar names? http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/nPZXM/ -- see the example - my expression works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(':input[id^="modal_"][id*="_'+ row +'_"]')
```

Though a better HTML setup would be single element wrapping inputs.

Comment: XXX is any combination of character.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all children and check if the id contains the string you want. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul').children().each(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        if (typeof(id) !== 'undefined') {
            if (id.indexOf('22') != -1) {
                $(this).css('color','red');
            }
        }
    });

});​
```

If you want it to run on your entire file, you can change it to

```
$('body').children()...
```

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RtKym/)

Comment: You only check if `22` exists in `id`, and don't check if `id` matches the desired pattern

Comment: Ins't easier to use the selector approach that zerkms and undefine post?

Comment: @zerkms: Ah, you're right. Didn't think that maybe the entire pattern needs to match.

Comment: @davidbuzatto: Definitely the selector approach is the way to go. I just had no idea they exist. Now that I do, I would not recommend using my solution.

Comment: @xbonez: Take a look: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ There are lots of variations. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[id^="modal_"][id$="_'+N+'"],select[id^="modal_"][id$="_'+N+'"]')
.attr('disabled','disabled');
```